# Angular animation is blocked after login popup

Tags: angular, animation, safari

I created an animation which fired after the social login is failed. It's working in chrome but not in safari. There after the animation works in safari, too. I don't have any idea, why.

See the following video, what I mean:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VdaNDjPnh4F2wULHy3CQZ5nvqZcQU33m/view?usp=sharing

1. I reload the page
2. Click the facebook login button
3. Show the login popup and thereafter it doesn't happened anything
4. Click again the facebook login button and the animation works

In chrome the animation works at first time too. So this bug be only safari.

This is my animation definition:

```
animations: [
    trigger('showConditions', [
      state('show', style({ left: '0' })),
      state('hide', style({ left: '100%' })),
      transition('show <=> hide', [
        animate('0.5s cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1)')
      ]),
    ]),
    trigger('showSignin', [
      state('show', style({ left: '0' })),
      state('hide', style({ left: '-100%' })),
      transition('show <=> hide', [
        animate('0.5s cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1)')
      ]),
    ])
  ],
```

And the animation fired when the showConditions parameter change:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.authSubscription = this.store.select('auth').subscribe((state: any) => {
      if (!!state.error) {
        this.error = state.error;
      }
      if (state.login.showConditions) {
        this.showConditions = state.login.showConditions;
        this.accessToken = state.provider.accessToken;
        this.provider = state.provider.type;
      }
      console.log(this.showConditions);
    });
  }
```

And I use this animation the following:

```
<div class="carousel-item active" [@showSignin]="!showConditions ? 'show' : 'hide'">...</div>
```

Thanks your help!
Tamas

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this problem. It was needed to use ngZone. So, I call a dispatch function in case of success fb login. If I put this function into the ngZone.run() function, then it works fine. My solution looks like the following:

```
this.ngZone.run(() => {
                this.store.dispatch(AuthActions.signInWithProviderStart({ accessToken, provider: 'facebook' }));
            });
```

I've created an instance for NgZone before.

More info for NgZone here: https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone